# AWS Cognito signing keys rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid

AWS Cognito doesn't seem to rotate the signing keys for the JWT tokens. Whereas other famous providers do: auth0, okta, etc.

Is there any way to make Cognito to rate the keys?